# how to update specific row using inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join

I need to update a specific row in a table, to select this row i need to use inner join, I wrote this:

```
UPDATE Items
SET  [Seq] = '0'
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM Items
inner join Dictionary on  items.Member = Dictionary.Member WHERE
 Items.ID = '1' and Items.Member ='23')
```

All rows in **Items** table were updated, not the specific row (the select statement works fine and I get the row I need)

Do I miss something?

Comment: you didn't specify a field for your where clause in your primary field your sub select should retrieve only the ID number you want to update so it'd be more like `WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Items....)`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Dave - I changed it to Items.ID (SELECT Items.ID...), and still no change.

Comment: you can simplify your query:`UPDATE Items SET  [Seq] = '0' FROM items inner join Dictionary on  items.Member = Dictionary.Member WHERE  Items.ID = '1' and Items.Member ='23'`

Comment: given your filtering on Items.id and Items.member, why do you need the dictionary table at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sql Server**

```
UPDATE Items
SET  Items.[Seq] = '0'
FROM Items inner join Dictionary 
on  items.Member = Dictionary.Member 
WHERE Items.ID = '1' and Items.Member ='23'
```

**Mysql**

```
UPDATE Items
 INNER JOIN Dictionary
ON items.Member = Dictionary.Member
SET  Items.[Seq] = '0'
WHERE Items.ID = '1' and Items.Member ='23'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server the format is:

```
Update a
set field1 = b.field2
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.id = b.table1id
where b.somefield = 'test'
```